# Date only in Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, date, timestamp

The users of my application are able to set a Date/Time OR Date (without time) for an item. The frontend is finished but I'm unsure how to store it into the database.

My first idea was to use MongoDate class like always and set time to 00:00:00 if the user has not selected a time. But with this later I'm unable to determine if "2014-11-20T00:00:00" is  a date only or a specified date/time combination.

The second idea was to store my dates in a custom format in the database.

```
{
   "type": "date"|"datetime",
   "timestamp": <TIMESTAMP>
}
```

If the ***type*** is "date" I will ignore the time part in ***timestamp***. With this structure I'm also able to sort and filter with a mix of Date-Time and Date-Only values.

But I'm not sure if it is a good solution.

Comment: It is OK solution, use it :) Or just use different field for different field types, like `timestamp_date` for date, `timestamp_time` for time, and `timestamp_datetime` for datetime.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I would think far too complicated.